# What is a more efficient way to locate disasm patterns in IDAPython?

Tags: ida, idapython, python

This is my first "serious" IDAPython script. As I sorta suspected, it's performing **waaaayyyyy** too slow so I wanted to ask for some pointers on this:

```
fp = MinEA()
end = MaxEA()

while fp < end:
    prev_inst = idc.prev_head(fp,MinEA())
    prev_prev = idc.prev_head(prev_inst,MinEA())
    next_inst = idc.next_head(fp,MaxEA())
    if idc.SegName(fp) == '.text' or idc.SegName(fp) == '.code':
        if idc.GetMnem(fp) == 'call':
            if (idc.GetOpnd(fp,0) == 'ds:GetProcAddress') or (idc.GetOpnd(fp,1) == 'ds:GetProcAddress'):
                if(idc.GetMnem(prev_inst) == 'push'):
                    if(idc.GetMnem(next_inst) == 'mov' and idc.GetMnem(prev_prev) == 'mov'):
                        print "GetProcAddress Found at %02X" % hex(fp)
```

This code is looking for this type of behavior (dynamic API loads):
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I typicall solve this by just walking over code references to the import.

Something like

```
for ref in CodeRefsTo(LocByName('GetTickCount'),True):
    print "%08x" % ref
```

This is quite powerful because unless I'm mistaken this also references snippets like this properly:

```
mov     esi, ds:LoadLibraryW
push    edi             ; lpLibFileName
call    esi ; LoadLibraryW
```

where the code reference is properly returned as the last line, not the first.

Then I typically walk the code backwards with `PrevHead` and `GetMnem` until I find the matching arguments.

Answer (score 0):

This is a comment esque answer, but I want to give this my best shot.

Also, I'd like you to understand I'm not the best with programming, and reversing itself, so this answer is probably nowhere near the best.

There is something very odd about this assembly that any reverse engineer would probably instantly notice, and I'm very glad you've noticed it to, thats 1 step down. You'll notice there is also at the end of each opcode byte, a pattern of bytes `... 37 12` is what I mainly am talking about, this means you can *possibly* check if the end of the opcode bytes are the same. This is a way to locate disasm patterns. Also, by the way, there are a few find signature libraries lying around for python. Here is one, https://pypi.python.org/pypi/libsigscan-python/20170124 (I'm not sure they work with IDAPyton, who knows, by the way, maybe IDAPython has an opcode byte finding function)

Hope this helped! Good luck :)

References:

http://ask-leo.com/what_is_signature_scanning.html

Comment: Uhm, other than that this should really be a comment (as you point out yourself), what's so odd about `37 12`? The whole instruction looks like an ordinary call with ds selector and an address. Now that the address is `0x1237....` seems logical looking at the line prefixes shown by IDA and another way to represent that call would be `call DWORD PTR ds:0x1237A1AC` ...

Comment: Sorry, I meant to put more of the bytecode pattern in, but you'll notice it forms a pattern.